# Mac Catalyst: How do I control tabbingMode with multi window support?

Tags: macos, nswindow, uiwindow, tabbing, mac-catalyst

If I add multi window support to my Catalyst app, menu items for showing and hiding the tab bar are automatically added. I want to be able to control this. However UIWindow does not seem to have a tabbingMode property. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you find a way to control it?

Comment: Not really. I have abandoned trying to use Mac Catalyst for now.

Comment: I understand… I hope the next macOS release will add a least some of the Mac-specific missing features.